# Is natural join the only elision of foreign key name?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose you have a department table with `DepartmentID` as primary key, and an employee table with `DepartmentID` as a foreign key. You can then use the fact that these columns have the same name, to perform a natural join that allows you to omit the column name from the query. (I'm not commenting on whether you should or not - that's a matter of opinion - just noting the fact that this shorthand is part of SQL syntax.)

There are various other cases in SQL syntax where you might refer to the column names with expressions like `employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID`. Are there any other cases where some kind of shorthand allows you to use the fact that the columns have the same name, to omit the column name?

Comment: Natural joins don't know about foreign keys, just column names.

Comment: Inner join with `using` can do it in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not know directly about foreign keys; it just has foreign key *constraints*, which prevent you from creating invalid data. When you have a foreign key, you would want both a constraint and to do joins on it, but the database does not automatically derive one from the other.

Anyway, when you are using a join on two columns with the same names:

```
SELECT ...
FROM employee
JOIN department ON employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID
```

then you can replace the ON clause with the [USING clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

```
SELECT ...
FROM employee
JOIN department USING (DepartmentID)
```

> If there is a USING clause then each of the column names specified must exist in the datasets to both the left and right of the join-operator. For each pair of named columns, the expression "lhs.X = rhs.X" is evaluated for each row of the cartesian product as a boolean expression. Only rows for which all such expressions evaluates to true are included from the result set.
>   […]
>   For each pair of columns identified by a USING clause, the column from the right-hand dataset is omitted from the joined dataset. This is the only difference between a USING clause and its equivalent ON constraint.

(Omitting the duplicate column matters only when you are using `SELECT *`.  (I'm not commenting on whether you should or not – that's a matter of opinion – just noting the fact that this shorthand is part of SQL syntax.))